# OnChange in a map function with Hooks updates all fields

Tags: reactjs

I try to search names that are in a certain environment, but I always search in all elements.
This means that if I enter letters in a certain search field, React will put the same letters in all other search fields.
Due to the fact that all fields are "connected" with the same hook and this is then also updated, it is clear to me. But how do I solve the problem?

[image]

Here's my code

```
export default function WochenComponent({ wochen }) {

...
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState([]);

const handleChange = (event) => {
 setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
};

...

React.useEffect(() => {
const results = wochen.azubis.filter(
  (azu) =>
    azu.vorname.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
    azu.nachname.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
);
setSearchResults(results);
}, [searchTerm]);




return (
 <Container>
  <Row className="justify-content-center">
    {allePlaene.map((plan) => {
      return (
        <Col md={3} xs="auto" sm={6} key={plan._id}>
         
           ...

            <div style={{ height: "230px", overflowY: "scroll" }}>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <form>

                       /*The magic goes here */
                        <TextField
                          style={{ width: "100%" }}
                          label="Suche..."
                          value={searchTerm}
                          variant="outlined"
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                          /*The magic goes here */

                      </form>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  {searchResults.map((azubi) => (
                    <tr key={azubi.id}>
                      ....
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      );
    })}
   </Row>
   </Container>
  );
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have now implemented the changes, unfortunately without success.
If I enter a letter where there is a name, nothing is shown to me. What works is that not all fields are now assigned the value. But before that I got a result

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
 if (event.target.id != null) {
  setSearchTerm((prevSearchTerm) => ({
    ...prevSearchTerm,
    [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
  }));
  }
 };


 <TextField
      id={`item${index}`}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        label="Suche..."
        variant="outlined"
        value={searchTerm[`item${index}`]}
        onChange={handleChange}
 />
```

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE II **

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-wave-dd2u0?file=/src/DialogKarte.js

Comment: sand box is not working

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

This is occurring because you are using one state variable to represent each individual search field, so all search fields are using and updating this value. To achieve true separation of the search fields you will need to have a separate variable or key to represent each search field

**Solution**

Use a javascript object instead, with each key representing the different text fields

```js
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState({});

const handleChange = (event) => {
 setSearchTerm(prevSearchTerm => ({...prevSearchTerm, [event.target.id]: event.target.value}))
};
...
                   

    <TextField
       id={someKey} //Probably its index or something
       style={{ width: "100%" }}
       label="Suche..."
       value={searchTerm[someKey]}
       variant="outlined"
       onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't work. I can see (browser debugger) that the correct IDs are coming, but still all fields are updated or the results in all elements are re-rendered

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by all fields are updated or the results in all elements are re-rendered?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example how you need to do it.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const tt = [
  {
    content: 1
  },
  {
    content: 2
  },
  {
    content: 3
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState({
    item0: "",
    item1: "",
    item2: ""
  });
  const test = e => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    setInputValue({
      [id]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {tt.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {item.content}
            <input
              id={`item${index}`}
              type="text"
              value={inputValue[`item${index}`]}
              onChange={test}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[here is the sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ives-vjh1s?file=/src/App.js:0-860)

Comment: may be i misunderstood your problem. I have updated the code.

Comment: Ok , have add it